# How can I make table cells behave like UL LIs?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I have a page of generated HTML which I cannot edit. The page has a table which contains two rows and each row has 4 cells each. I want to force the cells to behave like unordered list items so that they display in a vertical list. I know this is horrible hacking, but it really is my only choice at the moment. Is there a way to get table cells to display vertically rather than horizontally?

Comment: Horrible situation, try playing with the TD's display properties.

Comment: Absolutely horrible. Any recommendations?

Comment: simple make it `display:block`. http://jsfiddle.net/53dmd0h3/

Comment: Thank you everyone for the speedy and useful responses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `display` property for cells.

Assume the class of your table is mytable, CSS code would be:

```
.mytable td {
    display: block;
}
```

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Loy6x24/1/

I wouldn't recommend this hack, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
td {
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wyqvwx0/1/)